# How do you view ETW events created by EventSource using Windows Performance Analyzer?

Tags: c#, performance, etw, wpa

I would like to fire ETW events using `EventSource` and view them with Windows Performance Analyzer.

I have a basic `EventSource`:

```
[EventSource(Name = "BasicEventSource")]
public class ETWLogger : EventSource
{
#if DEBUG
    private const bool ThrowOnError = true;
#else
    private const bool ThrowOnError = false;
#endif

    private ETWLogger(bool throwOnError) : base(throwOnError) { }

    private static ETWLogger _log;
    public static ETWLogger Log
    { get { return _log ?? (_log = new ETWLogger(ThrowOnError)); } }

    private static class Keywords
    {
        public const EventKeywords Perf = (EventKeywords) 1;
    }

    [Event(1, Keywords = Keywords.Perf, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void Startup() { WriteEvent(1, "StartUp"); }
}
```

When I record with Windows Performance Recorder (WPR), I don't see my provider or events in the Generic Events graph of Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA).

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: How did you start your session? This is one approach we have been using - http://svcperf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Realtime%2bWCF%2bSession&referringTitle=FAQs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPR doesn't know anything about your custom `EventSource`, so you have to create a recording profile so you can enable it. WPT ships with a couple of sample profiles that should help you get started.

The 8.1 version of WPR supports the same naming convention as PerfView, which means that you can use `*YourEventSource` instead of the GUID in the profile.

In my experience some of the `EventSource` features are not well supported in the 8.1 version of WPA. E.g. if you use tasks they won't show up correctly. However, the basic usage of `EventSource` works well with the 8.1 version of WPA/WPR when you create a recording profile for your `EventSource`.

Another option is to collect the trace using PerfView and analyze it with WPA (if you prefer that over PerfView).

Comment: I have created a profile and am recording events using WPR.  Things look as I expect when I open the .etl file in PerfView.  However, when I open the .etl file in WPA I see a guidinstead of my event source name and numbers instead of my event names.  Is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

WPR and WPA did not support EventSource, but do with the new 8.1 ADK. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2013/08/10/wpr-wpa-support-for-viewing-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx).

Comment: Vance released a custom version of PerfView (http://sdrv.ms/QnHpd4) here that could collect EventSource events and then those could be viewed in WPA. I suspect the recently released 1.5 version of PerfView supports this as well. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2013/12/09/perfview-version-1-5-has-been-released.aspx